# How to change db link before executing a sql query in java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

*The application uses Spring and Hibernate.*

Is it possible to change [dblink](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm), before executing a sql query in Java? Whether native JDBC or Hibernate?

I know it's possible to

> refer to a table or view on the other database by appending @dblink to
>   the table or view name

But I can't do that as the sql query is written by a user and I don't have control on it (it's too complicated to parse it).

This code above shows what I'm trying to do...

```
// TODO connect to the db link ??? 
List<Object> results = this.getSession().doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Object>(){

        @Override
        public String execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException
        {
            final ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(userQuery);
            // doing something with results....

        }

});
```

Comment: Instead of dblink you could connect to the target database directly and avoid using the @dblink annotation.

Comment: But is this a real database? I don't know what to put for the jdbc url driver `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<url>:1521/<service_name>` ?
I only have the db_link, the username, the password and the host

Comment: What do you mean by Is *it possible to change dblink, before executing a sql query in Java*?
As per my understanding, you want to connect to the database(using @dblink only) and execute your query to fetch the result set, right?

Comment: Yes it is, but may be there is other solutions as the post below shows (didn't test it yet). For the connexion I don't know what to put in the jdbc URL ...

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the problem if you run `select * from table@dblink`? The user don't write the select with @dblink? How do you know on which database you want to run the query. I don't understand what is your problem, as what you ask is a very strange thing to do(ie change the dblink)

Comment: Yes, the user don't write the select with @dblink. They choose the dblink by select one in a combobox and then the sql query has to be executed on the right db link.

Comment: If the statements are using ANSI join you can try to add `@dblink` after first word after `FROM` and after `JOIN`... and except situation like `join (`. And possibly some other rare situations...

Comment: What you are asking to do is definitely possible because DBLink can be created and altered through DB scripts. But creating dynamic DBLinks sounds like a huge security red flag to me. DBLinks are systematic connections into a database. By allowing user functionality to create DBLinks on the fly... you are opening your database to some serious vulnerabilities which is going to get you into trouble in the long run.

Comment: You can read the target of a DBLink (but not the password) with `select owner,db_link,username,host as service_desc from ALL_DB_LINKS`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a synonym in your schema referencing the table on the other database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM "SOURCE_SCHEMA"."SYNONYM_NAME" FOR "TARGET_SCHEMA"."TARGET_TABLE"@"DBLINK"
```

That way you can access the external table by the synonym name, shielding you from the exact physical location of the object:

```
SELECT * FROM SYNONYM_NAME
```

If you want to map this entity using Hibernate, you would use the synonym name just like any other object.

Comment: Sounds good, do you know if it's clean to create the synonym the time to retrieve the results and then remove it?

Comment: If that's a requirement, it shouldn't be a problem, Clemzd. It's not a complex procedure like creating a materialized view

Comment: After more thought it can't works. When you create the synonym you specify the table. But I can't have this information as the sql query is written by an user.

Comment: Also creating and dropping synonyms is enormous performance and resource overhead for simple queries that run milliseconds. Also you wouldn't able to use transactions because of implicit commit.

Comment: Using this approach you should make a synonym for every possible table in the remote databases. Then you should write a procedure that changes all the synonyms according to required dblink. Then you can run the query but only one query at a time: You cannot run queries in diferent db in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If all references in the query are through DB link(s) or fully qualified, you could do this:

- Create a new user in your (local) Oracle database
- Create private db links for that user that have same name as the ones you want replaced

  - If the original DB lniks are public, you need to only redefine the DB links you want redirected, else you need to redefine all of them
- Use this DB user in your Java application

Private DB links will take precedence over public DB links of the same name, or for private DB links the current user's ones will be used, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

1. Either you can create synonyms for all tables that need to be accessed using DB link. Create these links and let them be there in your connecting schema. Or,
2. You can write a method that parses userQuery to determine if the table is owned or if it is in DB link'ed schema and correspondingly append @DBLink to table name in passed query.

I'd prefer approach 1, as 2 might be difficult to achieve with complex queries

Is there a reason you do want to delete the synonym?

Answer (score 0):

I simply initialize a new connection to the dblink. As the username is unique, it works.

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", jdbcUrl);
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", userDbLinkName);
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", userDbLinkPassword);

final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
final SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
return sessionFactory.openSession();
```